# Update row in first table and insert a row into a second table in a single query

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I'm trying to figure it out how to insert a row into a table on updating a particular field in the second table.

Let's say I have table 1 (`dif`):

```
CREATE TABLE dif
(
    Position INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pKey SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Number SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dif
ADD CONSTRAINT dif_article_pKey_fk
FOREIGN KEY (pKey) REFERENCES article (pKey) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

and table 2 (`article`):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (
  pKey smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  Number SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
  PRIMARY KEY (pKey)
);
```

The table article is populated with some data and should be only updated. Table "dif" is empty at the beginning. So, let's say I'm updating the fields on "article" like this:

```
UPDATE article SET pKey = 15, Name = SomeName,  Number = 22 WHERE pKey=15;
```

Can I somehow combine the UPDATE query with this?

```
INSERT  INTO  dif (pKey, Number) VALUES (15, 12);
```

The "12" is the difference between the "article.Number" before and after UPDATE.

Comment: just make a stored proc that has a transaction. To the caller, it is one query

Comment: Do you need to [create a trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) on the table being updated where the action is to insert into the other table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can make a stored procedure that does both of those things and then execute it in a single statement.

```
create procedure GiveThisABetterName
(
    in pKey int,
    in newNumber int,
    in currentNumber int,
    in newName varchar(100)
)
begin
    update 
        article 
    set 
        Name = newName, Number = newNumber 
    where 
        pKey = pKey;

    insert into dif (pKey, Number) values (pKey, newNumber);
end
```

My mysql syntax is rusty, but that should be close. Then when you want to execute it:

```
call GiveThisABetterName(12, 15, 22, 'Some Name');
```

EDIT: After reading your question again, it seems to me that you're trying to make your data model track audit information that it's just not set up to accommodate naturally. Do you have control over the model? If so, consider something like this (see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2efd/3) for a working example of what's below):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article (
  pKey smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pKey)
);

CREATE TABLE ArticleNumbers
(
    Counter int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pKey SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Number SMALLINT(3) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    Difference SMALLINT(3)
);

ALTER TABLE ArticleNumbers
    ADD CONSTRAINT ArticleNumbers_article_pKey_fk
        FOREIGN KEY (pKey) REFERENCES article (pKey) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Maybe add a few views to make things easier:

```
CREATE VIEW GroupedArticleNumbers
as
select pKey, max(Counter) as Counter
from ArticleNumbers
group by pKey;

CREATE VIEW CurrentArticles 
as 
select article.pKey, article.Name, numbers.Number, numbers.Difference 
from article 
left outer join GroupedArticleNumbers filter on article.pKey = filter.pKey
left outer join ArticleNumbers numbers on filter.Counter = numbers.Counter;
```

Since you can track the number separately from the base record now but still easily determine what the current number is, you can now combine your update and insert statement functionality. See below.

First, some test data:

```
insert into article (Name) values ('Test');
insert into ArticleNumbers (pKey, Number, Difference) values (1, 10, null);
insert into ArticleNumbers (pKey, Number, Difference) select 1, 20, 20 - Number from CurrentArticles where pKey = 1;
insert into ArticleNumbers (pKey, Number, Difference) select 1, 50, 50 - Number from CurrentArticles where pKey = 1;
insert into ArticleNumbers (pKey, Number, Difference) select 1, 15, 15 - Number from CurrentArticles where pKey = 1;
```

See how nicely that works out once the overhead of setting up the schema has been done?

To get the current number for the article we created:

```
select * from currentarticles where pKey = 1
```

To get the number history for that article:

```
select * from article
left outer join articlenumbers on article.pkey = articlenumbers.pkey
order by counter asc
```

If you're willing to mess with your data model, you can have an alternative to stored procedures.

Alternatively, if you want to use triggers as [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) suggested, something like this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
 pKey smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_roman_ci NOT NULL,
  Number SMALLINT(3) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pKey)
);

CREATE TABLE ArticleNumbers
(
    Counter int UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pKey SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Number SMALLINT(3) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    Difference SMALLINT(3)
);

delimiter $
create trigger tr_u_article
before update on article
for each row
begin
  insert into ArticleNumbers (pKey, Number, Difference) select old.pKey,     new.Number, new.Number - old.Number
  end;
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the semicolons, stranger!

Comment: He may want the net calculated, but the question is not clear on how that is performed (prev value, null converted to 0, etc etc)

Comment: Thanks @S.C.  Unfortunately modifying the table design would break too many things. The trigger is that i actually needed.